# Dropdown Login Menu using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a drop-down login box using Javascript, but it will just not work with the code I'm trying.

HTML:

```
<div id="links">

        <div id="links-wrap">

            <ul class="link">

                <li>
                    <a class="link1" href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="link2" href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="link3" href="#">Login</a>

                    <div id="login_wrap">

                        <div class="login_menu">

                            <form action="" method="post">
                                Username:</br> <input id="username" type="text" name="username" size="16">
                                Password: <input id="password" type="password" size="16" autocomplete="off">
                                <br>
                                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
                            </form>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.link {
color: #3e3e3e;
display: block;
letter-spacing: 2px;
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
}

#links-wrap {
float: right;
width: auto;
margin-top:-12px;
font-weight:600;
}

li {

padding-right:50px;
display:list-item;
text-align:-webkit-match-parent;
display : inline-block;
}


.login {

}

#username {
width:160px;
}

#password {
width:160px;
}

#submit {
margin-left:32.5%;
margin-top:10px;
}

.login_menu {
background-color:white;
border:1px solid black;
width: 180px;
height: 125px;
position: fixed;
margin-left: -60px;
margin-top:10px;
z-index:10;
font-size:10px;

}

#login_wrap {
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".link3").click(function() {
     $(this).children("#login_wrap").css("visibility","visible");
  });

});
```

I have tried multiple combinations of the the above code to no avail and I'm sure that somebody more experience could probably help me.

Can anybody help point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: The div with the form in it won't display when the anchor is clicked. I have tested that jQuery is working and it is so that's not the problem so it's an error on my part that I can't figure out for the life of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed some of your code. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sSnXz/1/)'s a link to a working example.

Then main error in your code was `$(this).children("#login_wrap")`. There is nothing wrong with the syntax, but it needs to be `$(this).parent().children("#login_wrap")` since `this` is wrapped in an `<a>` tag.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gDkBs/) is the old example that I wrote, previously. This one alternatively uses the `toggle` function to add a more pleasing display and the ability to close the login box.

Comment: I updated my example to more closely reflect the code you have written. You can use the old link or the new one, both work.

Answer (score 0):

`#login_wrap` is not a child of `$(".link3")`. Try:

```
$(".link3").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("#login_wrap").css("visibility","visible");
});
```

Or just (as div ID considered tio be unique in a DOM):

```
$(".link3").click(function() {
    $("#login_wrap").css("visibility","visible");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".link3").click(function() {
     $(this).parent().find("#login_wrap").toggle();
  });

});
```

I recommend looking for the parent first, then look for the children. In this case the parent serves as the context for your tags. This would create a more maintainable code. Because when you use .siblings() or some function to look for the login control, your javascript code is coupled to the current position of the tags. In the future, if you modify the position, like nested in 1 more level,  your code would fail. And in case you have multiple controls on the page, this code still works fine and open the correct control associated with the link.

**Side note**: In case you display multiple controls like this on the page, should not use id="login_wrapped", but change to class="login_wrapped" instead.